# GWT MVP Presenter Unable to Update View Listbox Component

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-platform

I am writing a GWT MVP application using the gwt-platform library (very nice once you get used to it). My issue occurs when my presenter attempts to update the contents of a Listbox. The problem occurs on line 66 of the below file:

https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jason/mapmaker/client/presenter/MapmakerStackPanelPresenter2.java

I am sure that the application is calling the onSuccess() method (a breakpoint in the debugger works), and that the result is populated.

One thing I've noticed is that the associated view, MapmakerStackPanelViewImpl2.java, seems to be initialized twice. I find myself wondering if I'm trying to update a control on that view that is not attached to the actual user interface. That file is here:

https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jason/mapmaker/client/view/MapmakerStackPanelView2.java

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your class GetMtfccTypesResult implements serializable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there were two copies of the view floating around. I used Gin to inject the view into the constructor of the presenter, and problem went away.